# Capistrano Handling Files not Tracked in VCS

Tags: ruby, web-applications, deployment, capistrano

If I have files not tracked by any VCS, say for example jquery plugin files, how do I make Capistrano work with them?

Can I just upload them manually to the "shared" folder? or does Capistrano automatically handle "non-VCS-ed" files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good question to ask is: why are they not in VCS?

Comment: let's say a jquery plugin that has 3 js files, lots of image files and lots of css files. Why track them if you will not modify them and they are not available as submodules?

Comment: Then how do you handle version changes? You need to track the version of dependencies *somehow*—if it can't be a submodule or gem then the actual file is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy arbitrary files with capistrano via scp like this:

```
task :copy_files do
  top.upload('path/to/files', "#{shared_path}", {:via => :scp, :recursive => true})
end
```